# Text Input with Label Effects iussue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using this code.

This works fine but one issue: when I put an input in one field and then go to the next one, their label goes mixup with input. You'll get an idea when you check my code.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="container">

        <h2>Input with Label Effects</h2>
        <div class="col-3 input-effect">
            <input class="effect-16" type="text" placeholder="">
            <label>First Name</label>
            <span class="focus-border"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3 input-effect">
            <input class="effect-17" type="text" placeholder="">
            <label>First Name</label>
            <span class="focus-border"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3 input-effect">
            <input class="effect-18" type="text" placeholder="">
            <label>First Name</label>
            <span class="focus-border"></span>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>


/*= Reset CSS 
============= */
html, body {border: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
body {font: 14px "Lato", Arial, sans-serif; min-width: 100%; min-height: 100%; color: #666;}
.container{margin: 0 auto; max-width: 1200px;}
*{margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box;}
.row{float: left; width: 100%; padding: 20px 0 50px;}
h2{text-align: center; color: #2079df; font-size: 28px; float: left; width: 100%; margin: 30px 0; position: relative; line-height: 58px; font-weight: 400;}
h2:before{content: ""; position: absolute; left: 50%; bottom: 0; width: 100px; height: 2px; background-color: #2079df; margin-left: -50px;}
/*= Reset CSS End
================= */

/*= input focus effects css
=========================== */
:focus{outline: none;}

.col-3{float: left; width: 27.33%; margin: 40px 3%; position: relative;} /* necessary to give position: relative to parent. */
input[type="text"]{font: 15px/24px "Lato", Arial, sans-serif; color: #333; width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box; letter-spacing: 1px;}

.effect-16, 
.effect-17, 
.effect-18{border: 0; padding: 4px 0; border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; background-color: transparent;}

.effect-16 ~ .focus-border{position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0; width: 0; height: 2px; background-color: #3399FF; transition: 0.4s;}
.effect-16:focus ~ .focus-border,
.has-content.effect-16 ~ .focus-border{width: 100%; transition: 0.4s;}
.effect-16 ~ label{position: absolute; left: 0; width: 100%; top: 9px; color: #aaa; transition: 0.3s; z-index: -1; letter-spacing: 0.5px;}
.effect-16:focus ~ label, .has-content.effect-16 ~ label{top: -16px; font-size: 12px; color: #3399FF; transition: 0.3s;}



// JavaScript for label effects only
    $(window).load(function(){
        $(".col-3 input").val("");

        $(".input-effect input").focusout(function(){
            if($(this).val() != ""){
                $(this).addClass("has-content");
            }else{
                $(this).removeClass("has-content");
            }
        })
    });
```

fiddle:- https://codepen.io/Balvant_Ahir/pen/wxZjxP

Comment: I apologize, but can you clarify please?  Possibly putting your code into a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) will help illustrate your problem.

Comment: added codepen link

Comment: Do you have JQuery loaded ? Because your jsfiddle shows us that you need it

Comment: yes i added, i have one one issue, when i enter first name and than go to next field called last name, so first name label and text mixup.

Comment: I don't know what is the problem with JQuery, I never use it, so i posted an answer in Vanilla JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include Jquery in your project.

Add the follwing line in your html

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```js
// JavaScript for label effects only
 $(window).load(function(){
  $(".col-3 input").val("");
  
  $(".input-effect input").focusout(function(){
   if($(this).val() != ""){
    $(this).addClass("has-content");
   }else{
    $(this).removeClass("has-content");
   }
  })
 });
```

```css
/*= Reset CSS 
============= */
html,
body {
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  font: 14px "Lato", Arial, sans-serif;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  color: #666;
}
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1200px;
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.row {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px 0 50px;
}
h2 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #2079df;
  font-size: 28px;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 30px 0;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 58px;
  font-weight: 400;
}
h2:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #2079df;
  margin-left: -50px;
}
/*= Reset CSS End
================= */

:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.col-3 {
  float: left;
  width: 27.33%;
  margin: 40px 3%;
  position: relative;
} /* necessary to give position: relative to parent. */
input[type="text"] {
  font: 15px/24px "Lato", Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #333;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}



.effect-16,
.effect-17,
.effect-18 {
  border: 0;
  padding: 4px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.effect-16 ~ .focus-border {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #3399ff;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
.effect-16:focus ~ .focus-border,
.has-content.effect-16 ~ .focus-border
{
  width: 100%;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
.effect-16 ~ label {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  top: 9px;
  color: #aaa;
  transition: 0.3s;
  z-index: -1;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
}
.effect-16:focus ~ label,
.has-content.effect-16 ~ label {
  top: -16px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #3399ff;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.effect-17 ~ .focus-border {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #3399ff;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
.effect-17:focus ~ .focus-border,
.has-content.effect-17 ~ .focus-border {
  width: 100%;
  transition: 0.4s;
  left: 0;
}
.effect-17 ~ label {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  top: 9px;
  color: #aaa;
  transition: 0.3s;
  z-index: -1;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
}
.effect-17:focus ~ label,
.has-content.effect-17 ~ label {
  top: -16px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #3399ff;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.effect-18 ~ .focus-border {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  z-index: 99;
}
.effect-18 ~ .focus-border:before,
.effect-18 ~ .focus-border:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #3399ff;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
.effect-18 ~ .focus-border:after {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
}
.effect-18:focus ~ .focus-border:before,
.effect-18:focus ~ .focus-border:after,
.has-content.effect-18 ~ .focus-border:before,
.has-content.effect-18 ~ .focus-border:after {
  width: 50%;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
.effect-18 ~ label {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  top: 9px;
  color: #aaa;
  transition: 0.3s;
  z-index: -1;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
}
.effect-18:focus ~ label,
.has-content.effect-18 ~ label {
  top: -16px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #3399ff;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.effect-16:empty{
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="container">
     
        <h2>Input with Label Effects</h2>
        <div class="col-3 input-effect">
         <input class="effect-16" type="text" placeholder="">
            <label>First Name</label>
            <span class="focus-border"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3 input-effect">
         <input class="effect-17 " type="text" placeholder="">
            <label>First Name</label>
            <span class="focus-border"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3 input-effect">
         <input class="effect-18" type="text" placeholder="">
            <label>First Name</label>
            <span class="focus-border"></span>
        </div>
      
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just replace your JQuery code by Vanilla JS and ... enjoy !

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.input-effect input').forEach(element => {
  element.addEventListener('focusout', function () {
    if(this.value && !this.classList.contains('has-content')){
      this.classList.add('has-content')
    } else if (!this.value){
      this.classList.remove('has-content')
    }
  })
})
```

```css
/*= Reset CSS 
============= */
html, body {border: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
body {font: 14px "Lato", Arial, sans-serif; min-width: 100%; min-height: 100%; color: #666;}
.container{margin: 0 auto; max-width: 1200px;}
*{margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box;}
.row{float: left; width: 100%; padding: 20px 0 50px;}
h2{text-align: center; color: #2079df; font-size: 28px; float: left; width: 100%; margin: 30px 0; position: relative; line-height: 58px; font-weight: 400;}
h2:before{content: ""; position: absolute; left: 50%; bottom: 0; width: 100px; height: 2px; background-color: #2079df; margin-left: -50px;}
/*= Reset CSS End
================= */

/*= input focus effects css
=========================== */
:focus{outline: none;}

.col-3{float: left; width: 27.33%; margin: 40px 3%; position: relative;} /* necessary to give position: relative to parent. */
input[type="text"]{font: 15px/24px "Lato", Arial, sans-serif; color: #333; width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box; letter-spacing: 1px;}

.effect-1, 
.effect-2, 
.effect-3{border: 0; padding: 7px 0; border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;}

.effect-1 ~ .focus-border{position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0; width: 0; height: 2px; background-color: #3399FF; transition: 0.4s;}
.effect-1:focus ~ .focus-border{width: 100%; transition: 0.4s;}

.effect-2 ~ .focus-border{position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 50%; width: 0; height: 2px; background-color: #3399FF; transition: 0.4s;}
.effect-2:focus ~ .focus-border{width: 100%; transition: 0.4s; left: 0;}

.effect-3 ~ .focus-border{position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 2px; z-index: 99;}
.effect-3 ~ .focus-border:before, 
.effect-3 ~ .focus-border:after{content: ""; position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0; width: 0; height: 100%; background-color: #3399FF; transition: 0.4s;}
.effect-3 ~ .focus-border:after{left: auto; right: 0;}
.effect-3:focus ~ .focus-border:before, 
.effect-3:focus ~ .focus-border:after{width: 50%; transition: 0.4s;}

.effect-4,
.effect-5,
.effect-6{border: 0; padding: 5px 0 7px; border: 1px solid transparent; border-bottom-color: #ccc; transition: 0.4s;}

.effect-4:focus,
.effect-5:focus,
.effect-6:focus{padding: 5px 14px 7px; transition: 0.4s;}

.effect-4 ~ .focus-border{position: absolute; height: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; transition: 0.4s; z-index: -1;}
.effect-4:focus ~ .focus-border{transition: 0.4s; height: 36px; border: 2px solid #3399FF; z-index: 1;}

.effect-5 ~ .focus-border{position: absolute; height: 36px; bottom: 0; left: 0; width: 0; transition: 0.4s;}
.effect-5:focus ~ .focus-border{width: 100%; transition: 0.4s; border: 2px solid #3399FF;}

.effect-6 ~ .focus-border{position: absolute; height: 36px; bottom: 0; right: 0; width: 0; transition: 0.4s;}
.effect-6:focus ~ .focus-border{width: 100%; transition: 0.4s; border: 2px solid #3399FF;}

.effect-7,
.effect-8,
.effect-9{border: 1px solid #ccc; padding: 7px 14px 9px; transition: 0.4s;}

.effect-7 ~ .focus-border:before,
.effect-7 ~ .focus-border:after{content: ""; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 50%; width: 0; height: 2px; background-color: #3399FF; transition: 0.4s;}
.effect-7 ~ .focus-border:after{top: auto; bottom: 0;}
.effect-7 ~ .focus-border i:before,
.effect-7 ~ .focus-border i:after{content: ""; position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 0; width: 2px; height: 0; background-color: #3399FF; transition: 0.6s;}
.effect-7 ~ .focus-border i:after{left: auto; right: 0;}
.effect-7:focus ~ .focus-border:before,
.effect-7:focus ~ .focus-border:after{left: 0; width: 100%; transition: 0.4s;}
.effect-7:focus ~ .focus-border i:before,
.effect-7:focus ~ .focus-border i:after{top: 0; height: 100%; transition: 0.6s;}

.effect-8 ~ .focus-border:before,
.effect-8 ~ .focus-border:after{content: ""; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 0; height: 2px; background-color: #3399FF; transition: 0.3s;}
.effect-8 ~ .focus-border:after{top: auto; bottom: 0; left: auto; right: 0;}
.effect-8 ~ .focus-border i:before,
.effect-8 ~ .focus-border i:after{content: ""; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 2px; height: 0; background-color: #3399FF; transition: 0.4s;}
.effect-8 ~ .focus-border i:after{left: auto; right: 0; top: auto; bottom: 0;}
.effect-8:focus ~ .focus-border:before,
.effect-8:focus ~ .focus-border:after{width: 100%; transition: 0.3s;}
.effect-8:focus ~ .focus-border i:before,
.effect-8:focus ~ .focus-border i:after{height: 100%; transition: 0.4s;}

.effect-9 ~ .focus-border:before,
.effect-9 ~ .focus-border:after{content: ""; position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; width: 0; height: 2px; background-color: #3399FF; transition: 0.2s; transition-delay: 0.2s;}
.effect-9 ~ .focus-border:after{top: auto; bottom: 0; right: auto; left: 0; transition-delay: 0.6s;}
.effect-9 ~ .focus-border i:before,
.effect-9 ~ .focus-border i:after{content: ""; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 2px; height: 0; background-color: #3399FF; transition: 0.2s;}
.effect-9 ~ .focus-border i:after{left: auto; right: 0; top: auto; bottom: 0; transition-delay: 0.4s;}
.effect-9:focus ~ .focus-border:before,
.effect-9:focus ~ .focus-border:after{width: 100%; transition: 0.2s; transition-delay: 0.6s;}
.effect-9:focus ~ .focus-border:after{transition-delay: 0.2s;}
.effect-9:focus ~ .focus-border i:before,
.effect-9:focus ~ .focus-border i:after{height: 100%; transition: 0.2s;}
.effect-9:focus ~ .focus-border i:after{transition-delay: 0.4s;}

.effect-10, 
.effect-11, 
.effect-12,
.effect-13,
.effect-14,
.effect-15{border: 0; padding: 7px 15px; border: 1px solid #ccc; position: relative; background: transparent;}

.effect-10 ~ .focus-bg{position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: #ededed; opacity: 0; transition: 0.5s; z-index: -1;}
.effect-10:focus ~ .focus-bg{transition: 0.5s; opacity: 1;}

.effect-11 ~ .focus-bg{position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; width: 0; height: 100%; background-color: #ededed; transition: 0.3s; z-index: -1;}
.effect-11:focus ~ .focus-bg{transition: 0.3s; width: 100%;}

.effect-12 ~ .focus-bg{position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 0; width: 0; height: 100%; background-color: #ededed; transition: 0.3s; z-index: -1;}
.effect-12:focus ~ .focus-bg{transition: 0.3s; width: 100%; left: 0;}

.effect-13 ~ .focus-bg:before,
.effect-13 ~ .focus-bg:after{content: ""; position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; width: 0; height: 100%; background-color: #ededed; transition: 0.3s; z-index: -1;}
.effect-13:focus ~ .focus-bg:before{transition: 0.3s; width: 50%;}
.effect-13 ~ .focus-bg:after{left: auto; right: 0;}
.effect-13:focus ~ .focus-bg:after{transition: 0.3s; width: 50%;}

.effect-14 ~ .focus-bg:before,
.effect-14 ~ .focus-bg:after{content: ""; position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; width: 0; height: 0; background-color: #ededed; transition: 0.3s; z-index: -1;}
.effect-14:focus ~ .focus-bg:before{transition: 0.3s; width: 50%; height: 100%;}
.effect-14 ~ .focus-bg:after{left: auto; right: 0; top: auto; bottom: 0;}
.effect-14:focus ~ .focus-bg:after{transition: 0.3s; width: 50%; height: 100%;}

.effect-15 ~ .focus-bg:before,
.effect-15 ~ .focus-bg:after{content: ""; position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 50%; width: 0; height: 0; background-color: #ededed; transition: 0.3s; z-index: -1;}
.effect-15:focus ~ .focus-bg:before{transition: 0.3s; width: 50%; left: 0; top: 0; height: 100%;}
.effect-15 ~ .focus-bg:after{left: auto; right: 50%; top: auto; bottom: 50%;}
.effect-15:focus ~ .focus-bg:after{transition: 0.3s; width: 50%; height: 100%; bottom: 0; right: 0;}


.effect-16, 
.effect-17, 
.effect-18{border: 0; padding: 4px 0; border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; background-color: transparent;}

.effect-16 ~ .focus-border{position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0; width: 0; height: 2px; background-color: #3399FF; transition: 0.4s;}
.effect-16:focus ~ .focus-border,
.has-content.effect-16 ~ .focus-border{width: 100%; transition: 0.4s;}
.effect-16 ~ label{position: absolute; left: 0; width: 100%; top: 9px; color: #aaa; transition: 0.3s; z-index: -1; letter-spacing: 0.5px;}
.effect-16:focus ~ label, .has-content.effect-16 ~ label{top: -16px; font-size: 12px; color: #3399FF; transition: 0.3s;}

.effect-17 ~ .focus-border{position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 50%; width: 0; height: 2px; background-color: #3399FF; transition: 0.4s;}
.effect-17:focus ~ .focus-border,
.has-content.effect-17 ~ .focus-border{width: 100%; transition: 0.4s; left: 0;}
.effect-17 ~ label{position: absolute; left: 0; width: 100%; top: 9px; color: #aaa; transition: 0.3s; z-index: -1; letter-spacing: 0.5px;}
.effect-17:focus ~ label, .has-content.effect-17 ~ label{top: -16px; font-size: 12px; color: #3399FF; transition: 0.3s;}

.effect-18 ~ .focus-border{position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 2px; z-index: 99;}
.effect-18 ~ .focus-border:before, 
.effect-18 ~ .focus-border:after{content: ""; position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0; width: 0; height: 100%; background-color: #3399FF; transition: 0.4s;}
.effect-18 ~ .focus-border:after{left: auto; right: 0;}
.effect-18:focus ~ .focus-border:before, 
.effect-18:focus ~ .focus-border:after,
.has-content.effect-18 ~ .focus-border:before,
.has-content.effect-18 ~ .focus-border:after{width: 50%; transition: 0.4s;}
.effect-18 ~ label{position: absolute; left: 0; width: 100%; top: 9px; color: #aaa; transition: 0.3s; z-index: -1; letter-spacing: 0.5px;}
.effect-18:focus ~ label, .has-content.effect-18 ~ label{top: -16px; font-size: 12px; color: #3399FF; transition: 0.3s;}

.effect-19,
.effect-20,
.effect-21{border: 1px solid #ccc; padding: 7px 14px; transition: 0.4s; background: transparent;}

.effect-19 ~ .focus-border:before,
.effect-19 ~ .focus-border:after{content: ""; position: absolute; top: -1px; left: 50%; width: 0; height: 2px; background-color: #3399FF; transition: 0.4s;}
.effect-19 ~ .focus-border:after{top: auto; bottom: 0;}
.effect-19 ~ .focus-border i:before,
.effect-19 ~ .focus-border i:after{content: ""; position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 0; width: 2px; height: 0; background-color: #3399FF; transition: 0.6s;}
.effect-19 ~ .focus-border i:after{left: auto; right: 0;}
.effect-19:focus ~ .focus-border:before,
.effect-19:focus ~ .focus-border:after,
.has-content.effect-19 ~ .focus-border:before,
.has-content.effect-19 ~ .focus-border:after{left: 0; width: 100%; transition: 0.4s;}
.effect-19:focus ~ .focus-border i:before,
.effect-19:focus ~ .focus-border i:after,
.has-content.effect-19 ~ .focus-border i:before,
.has-content.effect-19 ~ .focus-border i:after{top: -1px; height: 100%; transition: 0.6s;}
.effect-19 ~ label{position: absolute; left: 14px; width: 100%; top: 10px; color: #aaa; transition: 0.3s; z-index: -1; letter-spacing: 0.5px;}
.effect-19:focus ~ label, .has-content.effect-19 ~ label{top: -18px; left: 0; font-size: 12px; color: #3399FF; transition: 0.3s;}

.effect-20 ~ .focus-border:before,
.effect-20 ~ .focus-border:after{content: ""; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 0; height: 2px; background-color: #3399FF; transition: 0.3s;}
.effect-20 ~ .focus-border:after{top: auto; bottom: 0; left: auto; right: 0;}
.effect-20 ~ .focus-border i:before,
.effect-20 ~ .focus-border i:after{content: ""; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 2px; height: 0; background-color: #3399FF; transition: 0.4s;}
.effect-20 ~ .focus-border i:after{left: auto; right: 0; top: auto; bottom: 0;}
.effect-20:focus ~ .focus-border:before,
.effect-20:focus ~ .focus-border:after,
.has-content.effect-20 ~ .focus-border:before,
.has-content.effect-20 ~ .focus-border:after{width: 100%; transition: 0.3s;}
.effect-20:focus ~ .focus-border i:before,
.effect-20:focus ~ .focus-border i:after,
.has-content.effect-20 ~ .focus-border i:before,
.has-content.effect-20 ~ .focus-border i:after{height: 100%; transition: 0.4s;}
.effect-20 ~ label{position: absolute; left: 14px; width: 100%; top: 10px; color: #aaa; transition: 0.3s; z-index: -1; letter-spacing: 0.5px;}
.effect-20:focus ~ label, .has-content.effect-20 ~ label{top: -18px; left: 0; font-size: 12px; color: #3399FF; transition: 0.3s;}

.effect-21 ~ .focus-border:before,
.effect-21 ~ .focus-border:after{content: ""; position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; width: 0; height: 2px; background-color: #3399FF; transition: 0.2s; transition-delay: 0.2s;}
.effect-21 ~ .focus-border:after{top: auto; bottom: 0; right: auto; left: 0; transition-delay: 0.6s;}
.effect-21 ~ .focus-border i:before,
.effect-21 ~ .focus-border i:after{content: ""; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 2px; height: 0; background-color: #3399FF; transition: 0.2s;}
.effect-21 ~ .focus-border i:after{left: auto; right: 0; top: auto; bottom: 0; transition-delay: 0.4s;}
.effect-21:focus ~ .focus-border:before,
.effect-21:focus ~ .focus-border:after,
.has-content.effect-21 ~ .focus-border:before,
.has-content.effect-21 ~ .focus-border:after{width: 100%; transition: 0.2s; transition-delay: 0.6s;}
.effect-21:focus ~ .focus-border:after,
.has-content.effect-21 ~ .focus-border:after{transition-delay: 0.2s;}
.effect-21:focus ~ .focus-border i:before,
.effect-21:focus ~ .focus-border i:after,
.has-content.effect-21 ~ .focus-border i:before,
.has-content.effect-21 ~ .focus-border i:after{height: 100%; transition: 0.2s;}
.effect-21:focus ~ .focus-border i:after,
.has-conten.effect-21 ~ .focus-border i:after{transition-delay: 0.4s;}
.effect-21 ~ label{position: absolute; left: 14px; width: 100%; top: 10px; color: #aaa; transition: 0.3s; z-index: -1; letter-spacing: 0.5px;}
.effect-21:focus ~ label, .has-content.effect-21 ~ label{top: -18px; left: 0; font-size: 12px; color: #3399FF; transition: 0.3s;}

.effect-22, 
.effect-23, 
.effect-24{border: 0; padding: 7px 15px; border: 1px solid #ccc; position: relative; background: transparent;}

.effect-22 ~ .focus-bg{position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; width: 0; height: 100%; background-color: transparent; transition: 0.4s; z-index: -1;}
.effect-22:focus ~ .focus-bg, 
.has-content.effect-22 ~ .focus-bg{transition: 0.4s; width: 100%; background-color: #ededed;}
.effect-22 ~ label{position: absolute; left: 14px; width: 100%; top: 10px; color: #aaa; transition: 0.3s; z-index: -1; letter-spacing: 0.5px;}
.effect-22:focus ~ label, .has-content.effect-22 ~ label{top: -18px; left: 0; font-size: 12px; color: #333; transition: 0.3s;}

.effect-23 ~ .focus-bg:before,
.effect-23 ~ .focus-bg:after{content: ""; position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; width: 0; height: 0; background-color: #ededed; transition: 0.3s; z-index: -1;}
.effect-23:focus ~ .focus-bg:before,
.has-content.effect-23 ~ .focus-bg:before{transition: 0.3s; width: 50%; height: 100%;}
.effect-23 ~ .focus-bg:after{left: auto; right: 0; top: auto; bottom: 0;}
.effect-23:focus ~ .focus-bg:after,
.has-content.effect-23 ~ .focus-bg:after{transition: 0.3s; width: 50%; height: 100%;}
.effect-23 ~ label{position: absolute; left: 14px; width: 100%; top: 10px; color: #aaa; transition: 0.3s; z-index: -1; letter-spacing: 0.5px;}
.effect-23:focus ~ label, .has-content.effect-23 ~ label{top: -18px; left: 0; font-size: 12px; color: #333; transition: 0.3s;}

.effect-24 ~ .focus-bg:before,
.effect-24 ~ .focus-bg:after{content: ""; position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 50%; width: 0; height: 0; background-color: #ededed; transition: 0.3s; z-index: -1;}
.effect-24:focus ~ .focus-bg:before,
.has-content.effect-24 ~ .focus-bg:before{transition: 0.3s; width: 50%; left: 0; top: 0; height: 100%;}
.effect-24 ~ .focus-bg:after{left: auto; right: 50%; top: auto; bottom: 50%;}
.effect-24:focus ~ .focus-bg:after,
.has-content.effect-24 ~ .focus-bg:after{transition: 0.3s; width: 50%; height: 100%; bottom: 0; right: 0;}
.effect-24 ~ label{position: absolute; left: 14px; width: 100%; top: 10px; color: #aaa; transition: 0.3s; z-index: -1; letter-spacing: 0.5px;}
.effect-24:focus ~ label, .has-content.effect-24 ~ label{top: -18px; left: 0; font-size: 12px; color: #333; transition: 0.3s;}
/*= input focus effects css End
=============================== */
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="container">
     
        <h2>Input with Label Effects</h2>
        <div class="col-3 input-effect">
         <input class="effect-16" type="text" placeholder="">
            <label>First Name</label>
            <span class="focus-border"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3 input-effect">
         <input class="effect-17" type="text" placeholder="">
            <label>First Name</label>
            <span class="focus-border"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3 input-effect">
         <input class="effect-18" type="text" placeholder="">
            <label>First Name</label>
            <span class="focus-border"></span>
        </div>
      
    </div>
</div>
```